# Jumping towards the character’ s orientation

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I am making a 2d game in which the character falls on a slope and rotates while falling with a fixed rotation. When touching the ground the character jumps at an angle relative to the slope. I want it to always jump towards the orientation of itself, meaning towards his head, no matter what orientation it has at the moment when it is touching the ground with its legs. I attached a picture to make myself more understandable, and my code so far. I am new to unity and I hope you can help me with this problem. Thank you very much!

```
private void FixedUpdate() 
{
    IsTouchingGround = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheckPoint.position, groundCheckRadius, GroundLayer);
    if (IsTouchingGround)
    {
        rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(rigidBody.velocity.x, JumpPower);
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming it is a `Rigibody2D` I would just do e.g.

```
rigidBody.velocity = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rigidbody.rotation) * Vector2.up * JumpPower;
```

or basically this about equals using

```
rigidBody.velocity = transform.up * JumpPower;
```

so no need / use of maintaining the `X` velocity and rotate the resulting vector by the current rotation.